# Joomla component title

Tags: joomla, joomla-component, joomla3.5

I am not joomla developer. I am using some free component but can't change component admin page title. Can you please help me to change the title of the component? Please see the attached screenshot.[d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMFVz.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the screenshot here => [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16xXP.png)